# What is /bin/sh -c?

Tags: linux, sh

What does `/bin/sh -c` mean? What does `-c` do?

Answer (score 72, accepted):

From the man-page of bash:

> `-c string`
>
> If the `-c` option is present, then commands are read from `string`. If there are arguments after the string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with `$0`.

**Example:**

```
$ bash -c ls
```

will launch bash and execute the command `ls`.

`/bin/sh` is usually a symlink to a shell.

Comment: How is that different to without `-c` ?

Comment: You can pass a script as argument, `bash myScript` but it will open `myScript` and interpret the commands. This is not the same as `bash -c someCommand`. Compare what happens if you do `bash ls` and `bash -c ls` for instance.

Comment: /bin/sh -c grep "cpu cores" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e 's/[^0-9]
The above command does not give desired result. Why is it so?
Whereas 
/bin/sh -c ls | grep c
works fine.
I am not getting this odd behavior. It would be great if you can explain it too.

Comment: I got it. It needs to be formatted string.
/bin/sh -c 'grep "$0" /proc/cpuinfo | uniq | sed -e "$1"' "cpu cores" 's/[^0-9]*//g' worked like a charm.

Comment: You have two options: `bash script.sh` or `bash -c 'ls -la'`. `-c` parameter is the command with its parameters, that will be passed to the `bash` command interpreter. If your standard command interpreter is `bash`, then `ls -la` and `bash -c 'ls -la'` are equivalent

Answer (score 2):

With -c (command) it returns to the first shell instead of let open a new one.
It is very similar to: `sudo su -l -c 'echo "run a command and return"'`
Example:

```sh
#sudo su -l knoppix -c 'echo "run a command as ${USER} and return"'
run a command as knoppix and return
#
```

Comment: Well, you do not have to give password with `/bin/sh`.

Comment: the sequence to execute in simple quotes, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Let's break it down.

`/bin/sh`: This launches a Bourne shell, a basic command-line interpreter that is available on most Unix-like operating systems.

`-c`: This option tells the shell to read the command from the following string. It allows you to specify a command inline, without the need to write a separate script file. This option works in both `sh` and `bash`.

For example, if you run:

```bash
/bin/sh -c "echo Hello, World!"
```

This command tells `sh` to execute the `echo Hello, World!` string.