# How to run a shell script from cocoa application using Swift?

Tags: swift, shell, cocoa, terminal

How can I run a shell script from cocoa application using Swift?

I have a shell script file.sh that I want to run from within my cocoa application. How can I do this using Swift?

Any help appreciated! :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

## Pre Swift 3

You can use `NSTask` ([API reference here](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/nstask)) for this.

A `NSTask` takes (among other things) a `launchPath` which points to your script. It can also take an array of `arguments` and when you are ready to launch your task, you call `launch()` on it.

So...something along the lines of:

```
var task = NSTask()
task.launchPath = "path to your script"
task.launch()
```

## Post Swift 3

As @teo-sartory points out in his comment below `NSTask` is now `Process`, documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/process)

The naming and way you call it has changed a bit as well, here is an example of how to use `Process` to call `ls`

```
let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/ls")
try? process.run()
```

If you want better access to/more control over the output from your invocation, you can attach a `Pipe` (documented [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/pipe)).

Here is a simple example of how to use that:

```
let process = Process()
process.executableURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: "/bin/ls")

// attach pipe to std out, you can also attach to std err and std in
let outputPipe = Pipe()
process.standardOutput = outputPipe

// away we go!
try? process.run()

//read contents as data and convert to a string
let output = outputPipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
let str = String(decoding: output, as: UTF8.self)
print(str)
```

#### Would you like to know more

You can have a look at:

- an example gist [here](https://gist.github.com/Seasons7/836d3676884a40c8c98a)
- [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/412573/4063602) (in Objective C)
- [This tutorial](https://www.raywenderlich.com/125071/nstask-tutorial-os-x) from Ray Wenderlich
- [This article](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/example-code/system/how-to-run-an-external-program-using-process) by Paul Hudson

Hope that helps you.

Comment: NSTask is now Process()

Answer (score 7):

I found this function on the web:

```
@discardableResult
private func shell(_ args: String) -> String {
    var outstr = ""
    let task = Process()
    task.launchPath = "/bin/sh"
    task.arguments = ["-c", args]
    let pipe = Pipe()
    task.standardOutput = pipe
    task.launch()
    let data = pipe.fileHandleForReading.readDataToEndOfFile()
    if let output = String(data: data, encoding: .utf8) {
        outstr = output as String
    }
    task.waitUntilExit()
    return outstr
}
```

Here's the call:

```
shell("/pathToSh/file.sh")
```

Comment: That's wrong. The full command from your func is: `/bin/sh -c sh /pathToSh/file.sh`
And this obviously doesn't work..

Comment: @AlessandroOrnano just re-tested with `shell("open /Folder/")` and it worked just fine. Maybe you should check what `-c` does... https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985193/what-is-bin-sh-c

Comment: Even your second example is wrong, `open` opens file from a shell, don't change directory. Your method launch `bash -c` that mean it will launch bash and execute the command after -c, so it's like `bash -c bash file.sh` and it doesn't work.

Comment: I never said I wanted to change the directory, I wanted to open it and it did. So on that note, it works. Now, the command `sh` is meant to run the script... Your version works as well though.