# Flag '-c' in kubernetes cronjobs command/args

Tags: kubernetes, command, args, kubernetes-cronjob

[Creating a Cron Job](https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/job/automated-tasks-with-cron-jobs/)

What does the flag '-c' do in the Kubernetes Cronjob?

```
kind: CronJob
metadata:
  name: hello
spec:
  schedule: "* * * * *"
  jobTemplate:
    spec:
      template:
        spec:
          containers:
          - name: hello
            image: busybox
            imagePullPolicy: IfNotPresent
            command:
            - /bin/sh
            - -c
            - date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
          restartPolicy: OnFailure
```

Comment: Hello, it is a standard shell. The "-c" stands for command. So it asks to the shell binary to run the date command and then echo a string.
You can maybe get a better understanding if you run "/bin/sh --help" in any linux container.

Comment: @François thanks for your answer!

Comment: Glad it helps :)

Answer (score 1):

Community wiki for clearness and further searches.

@François is completely correct. [`/bin/sh -c`](https://www.linux.org/docs/man1/bash.html) comes directly from unix and simply means command you issue after shell. This is NOT a parameter for k8s cronjob :

> If  the  -c option is present, then commands are read from string.  If
> there are arguments after the
> string, they are assigned to the positional parameters, starting with $0.

You can also check [What is /bin/sh -c?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3985193/what-is-bin-sh-c)

Answer (score 0):

The "-c" flag does not belong to the Cronjob, it is used by unix sh executing the command:

```
/bin/sh -c date; echo Hello from the Kubernetes cluster
```

So you need to read the documentation for unix sh, not kubernetes.

Comment: I never said that it has to do something with Kubernetes. I just encountered it in Cronjob doc. My question was: what does it do. @Francois response was rather helpful. Thanks for your answer anyway